# Remove suggester from azure search index

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I added a field to my index, and now I need to update my suggester to look at the new field. Is there any way of updating a suggester in the api or in the portal.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately the answer is no.  In order to add a field to a suggester you need to re-create the index.

Answer (score 1):

Suggesters are established at the time fields are created. You can always add fields to an index and when you do so you can also add this new field to a new or existing suggester as part of the same index update operation. What you cannot do is remove a field from a suggester (or in general remove a field from the index), or add a field to a suggester after the field has been created.